# Polymer 1.0 'array-style' path accessors, alternative to bracket notation in expressions

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The Polymer 1.0 documentation states:

> The path syntax doesn’t support array-style accessors (such as
>   users[0].name). However, you can include indexes directly in the path
>   (users.0.name).

How would one get around this in setting the path dynamically, and obtain the same behavior as the following example using Polymer 0.5? This is specifically in the context of generating forms for a model defined by an Object.

```
<template repeat="{{row in fieldset.rows}}">
<div layout horizontal flex>
    <template repeat="{{field in row}}" flex>
        <paper-field field="{{model.fields[field]}}" value="{{obj[field]}}">
        </paper-field>
    </template>
</div>
</template>
```

### edit:

Per https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1504:

> No near-term plans to support this. Polymer 0.5 had a complex expression parser used for bindings that we have eliminated for simplicity and performance. There are alternate patterns you can use today to achieve similar results that just require you to be more explicit.

What the alternate pattern would be to achieve two way data binding remains unclear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is true that Polymer 1.0 no longer supports `myObject[key]` in binding expressions. However, in your particular use-case, there are ways to sidestep this problem.

#### One-way data-binding

It is fairly simple to overcome this limitation when it comes to one-way data-binding. Simply use a computed property that accepts both the object and the key in question:

```html
<my-element value="[[getValue(obj, key)]]"></my-element>
```

```js
getValue: function(obj, key) {
  return obj[key];
}
```

#### Two-way data-binding

In the case of two-way data-binding, it is still possible to create a functional alternative to the binding expression `{{obj[key]}}` in Polymer 1.0. However, it will require taking into consideration the particular use-case in which you are hoping to implement the binding.

Taking into account the example in your question, it seems that you are doing work with some sort of table or fieldset. For the purposes of the example here, I will use a slightly different, yet very similar structure.

Let's assume that we have a `fieldset` object, and that this object is structured as such:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    { "name": "Name", "prop": "name" },
    { "name": "E-mail", "prop": "email" },
    { "name": "Phone #", "prop": "phone" }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "jdoe@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-1032"
    },
    {
      "name": "Allison Dougherty",
      "email": "polymer.rox.1337@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-2983"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike \"the\" Pike",
      "email": "verypunny@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-7148"
    }
  ]
}
```

If we want to create some sort of table-like output which represents this object, we can use two nested repeating templates: the first to iterate through the different rows, and the second to iterate through the different fields. This would be simple using the one-way data-binding alternative above.

However, achieving two-way data-binding is very different in this case. How is it do-able?

In order to understand how to come up with a solution, it is important to break down this structure in a way that will help us figure out what observation flow we should implement.

It becomes simple when you visualize the `fieldset` object like this:

```
fieldset
    -->  rows (0, 1, ...)
        -->  row
            -->  fields (name, email, phone)
                -->  value
```

And becomes *even simpler* when you factor in the **workflow of your element/application**.

In this case, we will be building a simple grid editor:

```
+---+------+--------+-------+
|   | Name | E-mail | Phone | 
+---+------+--------+-------+
| 0 | xxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxx |
+---+------+--------+-------+
| 1 | xxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxx |
+---+------+--------+-------+
| 2 | xxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxx |
+---+------+--------+-------+
```

There are two basic ways that data will flow in this app, triggered by different interactions.

- **Pre-populating the field value**: This is easy; we can easily accomplish this with the nested templates mentioned earlier.
- **User changes a field's value**: If we look at the application design, we can infer that, in order to handle this interaction, whatever element we use as an input control, it must have some sort of way of knowing:

  - The **row** it will affect
  - The **field** it represents

Therefore, first let's create a repeating template which will use a new custom element that we will call `basic-field`:

```html
<div class="layout horizontal flex">
  <div>-</div>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fieldset.fields]]" class="flex">
      <div class="flex">[[item.name]]</div>
  </template>
</div>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fieldset.rows}}" as="row" index-as="rowIndex">
  <div class="layout horizontal flex">
    <div>[[rowIndex]]</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fieldset.fields]]" class="flex">
      <basic-field class="flex" field="[[item]]" row="{{row}}"></basic-field>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

*(In the snippet above, you'll notice that I've also added a separate repeating template to generate the column headers, and added a column for the row index - this has no influence on our binding mechanism.)*

Now that we've done this, let's create the `basic-field` element itself:

```html
<dom-module>
  <template>
    <input value="{{value}}">
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'basic-field',
    properties: {
      row: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true
      },
      field: {
        type: Object
      },
      value: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

We have no need to modify the element's field from within the element itself, so the `field` property does not have `notify: true`. However, we will be modifying the contents of the row, so we do have `notify: true` on the `row` property.

However, this element is not yet complete: In its current state, it doesn't do any of the work of setting or getting its value. As discussed before, the value is dependent on the row and the field. Let's add a multi-property observer to the element's prototype that will watch for when both of these requirements have been met, and populate the `value` property from the dataset:

```js
observers: [
  '_dataChanged(row.*, field)'
],
_dataChanged: function(rowData, field) {
  if (rowData && field) {
    var value = rowData.base[field.prop];
    if (this.value !== value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

There are several parts to this observer that make it work:

- `row.*` - If we had just specified `row`, the observer would only be triggered if we set `row` to an entirely different row, thus updating the reference. `row.*` instead means that we are watching over the contents of `row`, as well as `row` itself.
- `rowData.base[field.prop]` - When using `obj.*` syntax in an observer, this tells Polymer that we are using path observation. Thus, instead of returning just the object itself, this means that `rowData` will return an object with three properties:

  - `path` - The path to the change, in our case this could be `row.name`, `row.phone`, etc.
  - `value` - The value that was set at the given path
  - `base` - The base object, which in this case would be the row itself.

This code, however, only takes care of the first flow - populating the elements with data from the `fieldset`. To handle the other flow, user input, we need a way to catch when the user has inputted data, and to then update the data in the row.

First, let's modify the binding on the `<input>` element to `{{value::input}}`:

```html
<input value="{{value::input}}">
```

Polymer does not fully automate binding to native elements as it doesn't add its own abstractions to them. With just `{{value}}`, Polymer doesn't know when to update the binding. `{{value::input}}` tells Polymer that it should update the binding on the native element's `input` event, which is fired whenever the `value` attribute of the `<input>` element is changed.

Now let's add an observer for the `value` property:

```js
value: {
  type: String,
  observer: '_valueChanged'
}

...

_valueChanged: function(value) {
  if (this.row && this.field && this.row[this.field] !== value) {
    this.set('row.' + this.field.prop, value);
  } 
}
```

Notice that we aren't using `this.row[this.field.prop] = value;`. If we did, Polymer would not be aware of our change, as it does not do path observation automatically (for the reasons described earlier). The change would still be made, but any element outside of `basic-field` that may be observing the `fieldset` object would not be notified. Using `this.set` gives Polymer a tap on the shoulder that we are changing a property inside of `row`, which allows it to then trigger all the proper observers down the chain.

Altogether, the `basic-field` element should now look something like this (I've added some basic styling to fit the `<input>` element to the `basic-field` element):

```html
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="basic-field">
  <style>
    input {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <input value="{{value::input}}">
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'basic-field',
    properties: {
      row: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true
      },
      field: {
        type: Object
      },
      value: {
        type: String,
        observer: '_valueChanged'
      }
    },
    observers: [
      '_dataChanged(row.*, field)'
    ],
    _dataChanged: function(rowData, field) {
      if (rowData && field) {
        var value = rowData.base[field.prop];
        if (this.value !== value) {
          this.value = value;
        }
      }
    },
    _valueChanged: function(value) {
      if (this.row && this.field && this.row[this.field] !== value) {
        this.set('row.' + this.field.prop, value);
      } 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Let's also go ahead and take the templates we've made before and throw them into a custom element as well. We'll call it the `fieldset-editor`:

```html
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="basic-field.html">

<dom-module id="fieldset-editor">
  <style>
    div, basic-field {
      padding: 4px;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div class="layout horizontal flex">
      <div>-</div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fieldset.fields]]" class="flex">
          <div class="flex">[[item.name]]</div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fieldset.rows}}" as="row" index-as="rowIndex">
      <div class="layout horizontal flex">
        <div>[[rowIndex]]</div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fieldset.fields]]" class="flex">
          <basic-field class="flex" field="[[item]]" row="{{row}}"></basic-field>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
    <pre>[[_previewFieldset(fieldset.*)]]</pre>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'fieldset-editor',
    properties: {
      fieldset: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true
      }
    },
    _previewFieldset: function(fieldsetData) {
      if (fieldsetData) {
        return JSON.stringify(fieldsetData.base, null, 2);
      }
      return '';
    }
  });
</script>
```

You'll notice we're using the same path observation syntax as we did inside of `basic-field` to observe changes to `fieldset`. Using the `_previewFieldset` computed property, we will generate a JSON preview of the fieldset whenever any change is made to it, and display it below the data entry grid.

And, using the editor is now very simple - we can instantiate it just by using:

```html
<fieldset-editor fieldset="{{fieldset}}"></fieldset-editor>
```

And there you have it! We have accomplished the equivalent of a two-way binding using bracket-notation accessors using Polymer 1.0.

If you'd like to play with this setup in real-time, I have it [uploaded on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/viQi9sAZwSw6el6pUHUQ?p=preview).

Comment: Fantastic! Very thorough! I saw all the effort you put into it and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a computed binding. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#computed-bindings

```html
<paper-field field="{{_computeArrayValue(model.fields, field)}}" value="{{_computeArrayValue(obj, field}}"></paper-field>

<script>
  Polymer({
    ...
    _computeArrayValue: function(array, index) {
      return array[index];
    },
    ...
  });
</script>
```

As an aside, you also need to update your repeat to dom-repeat https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat

Edit: Here is my ugly solution to the 2-way binding. The idea is that you have a calculated variable get the initial value and then update this variable upon updates with an observer.

```html
<!-- Create a Polymer module that takes the index and wraps the paper field-->
<paper-field field="{{fieldArrayValue}}" value="{{objArrayValue}}"></paper-field>

<script>
  Polymer({
    ...
    properties: {
            fields: { //model.fields
                type: Array,
                notify: true
            },
            obj: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true
            },
            arrayIndex: {
                type: Number,
                notify: true
            },
            fieldArrayValue: {
                type: String,
                computed: '_computeInitialValue(fields, number)'
            },
            objArrayValue: {
                type: String,
                computed: '_computeInitialValue(obj, number)'
            }
        },
    _computeInitialValue: function(array, index) {
      return array[index];
    },
    observers: [
            'fieldsChanged(fields.*, arrayIndex)',
            'objChanged(fields.*, arrayIndex)'
    ],
    fieldsChanged: function (valueData, key) {
       this.set('fieldArrayValue', this.fields[this.arrayIndex]);            
    },
    objChanged: function (valueData, key) {
       this.set('objArrayValue', this.obj[this.arrayIndex]);            
    },
    ...
  });
</script>
```

Edit 2: Updated the code in Edit 1 to reflect the obeserver changes pointed out by Vartan Simonian

Comment: +1! This is definitely the way to go for now. However, in hope of avoiding this scenario, I've begun a [discussion on the Polymer mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/hO78HHNr5vE) querying whether or not it would be possible to add support for bracket-notation array accessors without causing any performance issues. Hopefully the Polymer devs respond. :)

Comment: I presumed it was a performance issue that lead to this change. Unfortunately, the above solution doesn't duplicate the behavior of the bracket notation in 0.5 as changes to the input value are not reflected in the obj. I should have qualified further that I was hoping to achieve 2 way data binding.

Comment: @user241584 Oh! Well, that certainly clears things up a bit! And, if anything, it also gives some more to add to the discussion. I've gone ahead and added to the thread on the mailing list. In the meantime, at least to my knowledge, this particular scenario may not be supported. However, I encourage you to continue seeking solutions; perhaps someone might stop by with a workaround. I'm trying to think of one but I can't quite put together something that would do the trick.

Comment: @user241584 I'll add to the answer my ugly solution to the 2 way binding, but it does involve using way too many roundabout observers and a bunch of excess code that I think is not proper.

Comment: @blissfulyoshi Here's one way I thought of which may be a bit cleaner: http://plnkr.co/edit/1guDcUty0xe4ULnngs8E?p=preview ... and here's another method suggested by sjmiles from the Polymer team: http://jsbin.com/fohage/18/edit?html,output

Comment: @VartanSimonian Sorry, I feel sort of stupid right now, and not understanding how your solution is cleaner. I know I use computed just to get initial values, not for anything 2-way binding related. As for sjmiles's answer, I found it really cool, but you lose the power to manipulate the rest of the array (unless you pass it down, but then you need to ask why you bound to the array value). I don't know what user241584 needs, but I still want to give him all the original abilities he had. (Will update for the dual binding for the observer, thanks)

Comment: @blissfulyoshi Please don't feel stupid; I assure you if anyone is prone to making stupid mistakes, it's me. The one thing I feel is a bit cleaner is that in the example I threw up on Plunker, is that there are only two properties required for the binding to work: one referring to the object, the other to the key. and there's only one observer which handles both key and object.

Comment: @VartanSimonian Oh okay I see now, let me update the code again with the ready function to set the 2 default values.

Comment: Wait, is there code to give an undeclared property a default value, I actually can't find the code for it. @VartanSimonian do you know what it is?

Comment: @blissfulyoshi Among the property attributes such as `type: String` and `observer: 'propertyObserver'` you want to add one of the format `value: defaultValueGoesHere`.

Comment: @VartanSimonian But that means adding a property value, like I have with fieldArrayValue and objArrayValue right now, making it not possible for me  to remove them.

Comment: @blissfulyoshi By "undeclared property" do you perhaps mean, private property, one that isn't exposed to elements outside? If that's what you're going for you should be able to just add a line like `_privateProp: someValue` outside of the `properties` object.

Comment: @VartanSimonian yes, but unless I missed soemthing, that doesn't make my code any smaller So unless I missed something, I don't think I need to edit my code for now....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79709/discussion-between-vartan-simonian-and-blissfulyoshi).